# mongodb findUpdateOne replace object with object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Need to change object values (not an array)
Want to replace current mongodb object with javascript object.

mongodb document sample:

```
   _id: ObjectId("5ee16596c1583dee0d7a6cae")
   name: "Union Bay"
   code: "ub"
   configs: Object
      food: true
      toys: true
      bedding: true
      books: true
      tools: false
   owner: "Mary Smith"
]
```

What I get passed to me is an object of configs such as

```
   food: true
   toys: false
   bedding: false
   books: false
   tools: false
```

I can manually use updateOne by typing them all in with command line...

```
db.client.updateOne({"code": "ub"},{$set: {"configs":{"food": true, "toys": false, "bedding": false, "books": false, "tools": false}}})
```

But in my javascript I don't want to iterate through the object. I just want to pass the object to $set. I tried this...

configInfo is object like above with all the current settings as object

```
await Client.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
      code: "ub"
   },
   { $set: { configs: configInfo }},
);
```

unfortunately, it RESULTS in ...

```
[
   _id: ObjectId("5ee16596c1583dee0d7a6cae")
   name: "Union Bay"
   code: "ub"
   configs: Object
      food: true
   owner: "Mary Smith"
]
```

it only updates the first key/value set in the object. When what I want to do is actually replace the whole mongodb object with my javascript object. Resulting in this...

DESIRE RESULTS WOULD BE...

```
[
   _id: ObjectId("5ee16596c1583dee0d7a6cae")
   name: "Union Bay"
   code: "ub"
   configs: Object
      food: true
      toys: false
      bedding: false
      books: false
      tools: false
   owner: "Mary Smith"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `upsert`,

> upsert creates the object if it doesn't exist.
> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#Upsert

```
await Client.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
      code: "ub"
   },
   { $set: { configs: configInfo }},
   { upsert: true }
);
```

Comment: Nope. This resulted in the same data identified above as RESULTS. It only has to first configuration ( food: true ) and does not provide the remaining values as shown in DESIRE

Comment: try `Client.updateOne()` with upsert true, it should work https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne

Comment: unfortunately, Nagesh, that still does not update any values, but the first entry in the object.  This is what I tried...
let theClient = await Client.updateOne(
            {
                code: "ub",
            },
            { $set: { configs: configInfo } },
            { upsert: true }
        );